# What are the symbols for Migakibô?

Tags: words

I am researching the stone polishing techniques used to polish katana. I have come across the term Migakibô, which is a polishing rod used during the Shitamigaki (下磨き) stage of polishing, but I can not find the appropriate symbols, Kanji, Hiragani or Katakana, for Migakibô. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, requests for transcription are off-topic for this site. As a one-off, I can tell you that it's 磨き棒.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean following?

Kanji: 磨き棒

Hiragana: みがきぼう

Katakana: ミガキボウ

Alphabet for Japanese: migakibou ← easily understand for Japanese

## Superfluous

"磨き" means "polishing".
"棒" means "rod".

I found the word (磨き棒) at [here](https://www.togishi-touken.jp/%E7%A0%94%E7%A3%A8%E5%AE%9F%E6%BC%94/).

Comment: Thank you very much!